# Why is the const keyword is mandatory for defining template parameters?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I just wanted to know why should i make the variables that i pass to the function templates has to be const?

example:-

```
   #include <iostream>
   using std::cout;
   using std::endl;

   template< typename T>
   void printArray( T *array, int count )
   {
      for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
         cout << array[ i ] << " ";
      cout << endl;
   }

   int main()
   {
     const int ACOUNT = 5; // size of array a
     const int BCOUNT = 7; // size of array b
     const int CCOUNT = 6; // size of array c

     int a[ ACOUNT ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
     double b[ BCOUNT ] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7 };
     char c[ CCOUNT ] = "HELLO"; // 6th position for null

     cout << "Array a contains:" << endl;

     // call integer function-template specialization
     printArray( a, ACOUNT );

     cout << "Array b contains:" << endl;

     // call double function-template specialization
     printArray( b, BCOUNT );

     cout << "Array c contains:" << endl;

     // call character function-template specialization
     printArray( c, CCOUNT );
     return 0;
   }
```

Here in main function:-
I declare the variables

```
 const int ACOUNT = 5; // size of array a
 const int BCOUNT = 7; // size of array b
 const int CCOUNT = 6; // size of array c
```

as `const`. If I don't declare them as const then I would get an error "Uninitialized array".

Can anyone please let me know if that is the rule that the parameters sent to function templates has to be of const type?

Answer (score 4):

**I just wanted to know why should i make the variables that i pass to the function templates has to be const?**
No, You don't need to, the problem lies elsewhere.

In C++, You are not allowed to have **[Variable Length Arrays(VLA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)**.
Hence, When you declare an array the length should be declared as a compile time constant.

```
const  int ACOUNT = 5; // size of array a
const int BCOUNT = 7; // size of array b
const int CCOUNT = 6; // size of array c

int a[ ACOUNT ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
double b[ BCOUNT ] = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7 };
char c[ CCOUNT ] = "HELLO"; // 6th position for null
```

In above example, Without the `const`, your arrays would get declared as VLA and that is not allowed in C++.